# Geolocation API - Speed returns null

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am using the Geolocation API to try to access my speed and my lat/long coords. Both lat and long return fine, but speed returns `null` each time. I understand that if the device does not have the capability to return that information it will return `null`, however, I would expect my Samsung Galaxy S5 would have the capability to read the speed.

Below is some of my code:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        $('.speed').text("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    console.log("Updated")
    $('.speed').text("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + " Speed: " + position.coords.speed); 

getLinkInfo(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
}
```

Comment: I would expect the same from that device. However, based on my brief scan through the documentation, it seems that only if the feature is not supported will it return null. `"If the implementation cannot provide speed information, the value of this attribute must be null. Otherwise, the value of the speed attribute must be a non-negative real number."`